# how to show URL of SVG in image tag?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, svg

I have uploaded SVG file and here it is url of that file
https://d37rj1mm6ksgs8.cloudfront.net/1593781915039-safety-goggles.svg

i want to show this URL into image tag. but it is not working. If you click on above url you will see that a File downloads and that downloaded file shows on browser as SVG. \

how can i show that URL in image tag or is there any other way to show that file.

### Below is my code

```html
<div className="lecture-media media-image image-loaded" style={{ height: "220px", width: "400px", }}>
  <LazyImage src={value.image_id.url} alt="img." placeholder={({ imageProps, ref, })=> (
    <i ref={ref} className="icn icn-img-loading is-centered"></i> )} actual={({ imageProps }) => (
    <div className={`LazyImage-Actual`}>
      <img {...imageProps} />
    </div>
    )} />
</div>
```

Comment: @RobertLongson i checked images also have mime-type is application/octet-stream. and  they are shown on website . here is the URL of one image. https://d37rj1mm6ksgs8.cloudfront.net/1593773257491-Capture.PNG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [response-header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62776819/how-to-show-url-of-svg-in-image-tag) for the URL indicates that the mime-type is application/octet-stream you'd need to fix that to be image/svg+xml instead.

You'd need to fix it on the server i.e. change some configuration on cloudfront.